# What means the ~ symbol in the code?

Tags: c++

I'm learning Arduino (school and from myself).

We have the following code:

```
temp = Wire.read();
temp = ~temp;
temp = temp - 1;
```

This code is made to read, then print positive and negative values from a temp sensor. If you need more parts of the code, let me know.

I don't understand what does the `~` symbol, can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[As always, `~` in C++ is bitwise negation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)